# Show that $Z_n$ converges to $0$ in mean square

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $Z_n$ be a discrete random variable with mass function 
$\mathbb{P}(Z_n = n^\alpha)  = \frac{1}{n}$ and $\mathbb{P}(Z_n = 0 ) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}. $ I want to show that $Z_n$ converges to $0$ in mean square if and only if $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$.

So I want to show that 
$$\mathbb{E}(Z_n^2 ) = \sum_k k^2 \mathbb{P}(Z_n = k) \to 0 ~\text{as} ~ n \to \infty. $$
I am confused how to find the probabilities $\mathbb{P}(Z_n = 1), \mathbb{P}(Z_n = 2) , \ldots$ They are zero when they cannot be written as $n^\alpha$ so
$$\mathbb{E}(Z_n^2 ) = \sum_k k^2 \mathbb{P}(Z_n = n^\alpha),  $$
but I don't know what $n$ is.

I think I have the wrong approach

Comment: Hint: $\frac1n+\left(1-\frac1n\right)=1$ hence $P(Z_n=n^a)=\frac1n$, $P(Z_n=0)=1-\frac1n$ **and $P(Z_n=k)=0$ for every other $k$**. Thus, $$E(Z_n^2)=0\cdot P(Z_n=0)+n^{2a}\cdot P(Z_n=n^a)=\ldots$$